# uiautomatorviewer working on Android 6.0.1 but not working on 7.0 or 8.0

Tags: python, appium-android, uiautomatorviewer

`uiautomatorviewer` is working properly on android 6.0 but whenever I am trying the same thing on 7.0 or 8.0. it's showing error.

Ho to fix it?

Comment: Ensure that SDK Manager is updated to support newer versions of android.

Comment: already updated my SDK manager. Still, I am facing the same issue. After Clicking on the capture button from uiautomatorviewer, EOF(End of File) error is showing.